# Value of type 'String' has no member 'removeVowels'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a method that will remove any vowel from a given sentence. I created the function 'removeVowels' which in my mind seems right. But when I try to call that function after a given sentence I get the error "Value of type 'String' has no member 'removeVowels'".

```
var sent: String = "This website is for losers LOL!"

func removeVowels(sent: String) -> String {
    let vowels: [Character] = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]
    let result = String(sent.characters.filter{vowels.contains($0)})
    return result
}

print(sent.removeVowels)
```

Comment: Note that your function removes everything **but** vowels.

Comment: Btw, the proper name for a non-mutating function/method would be something like `removingVowels()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you made `removeVowels` a free-standing function, you need to call it using function syntax:

```
print(removeVowels(sent:sent))
```

You can make it an extension property of `String` class, in which case you need to use a different syntax:

```
extension String {
    var removeVowels {
        let vowels: [Character] = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]
        let result = String(self.characters.filter{!vowels.contains($0)})
        return result
    }
}
```

This invocation syntax will work now:

```
print(sent.removeVowels)
```

**Edit:** Your implementation was keeping vowels, rather than removing them.

Comment: I would recommend making this a method, rather than a computed property. Computed properties generally should be O(1) and IMO should feel like things that could actually have been stored on the instance itself; neither is the case here. Also, [as Martin says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658672/value-of-type-string-has-no-member-removevowels#comment78275401_45658672), the non-mutating name should be `removingVowels()`.

Answer (score 1):

Either you have to call the function

```
print(removeVowels(sent: sent))
```

---

Or you have to declare the function as a String extension and as variable

```
extension String {

    var removeVowels : String {
        let vowels: [Character] = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]
        let result = String(self.characters.filter{vowels.contains($0)})
        return result
    }
}
```

Then you can call

```
print(sent.removeVowels)
```

By the way, if you really want to **remove** the vowels you have to filter **`does not contain`** (`...filter{!vowels...`)

---

Alternatively you could use Regular Expression

```
extension String {
    var removingVowels : String {
        return self.replacingOccurrences(of: "[aeiou]", with: "", options: [.caseInsensitive, .regularExpression])
    }
}
```